# Working with output from joined tables with php oop

Tags: php, mysql, oop

As part of my learning OOP PHP, I have made a database object that includes the following method:

```
public static function find_by_sql($sql="") {
        global $database;
        $result_set = $database->query($sql);
        $object_array = array();
        while ($row = $database->fetch_array($result_set)) {
                $object_array[] = static::instantiate($row);
        }
        return $object_array;
}
```

and I can use this to retrieve and access data from a single table, however when I try to use it with joined tables, the object only gives me the data from the primary table e.g.

```
$sql = "SELECT s.name, m.id, m.firstName, m.lastName, m.dob";  
    $sql .= " FROM members AS m";
    $sql .= " LEFT JOIN mbr_sections AS ms ON m.id = ms.member_id";
    $sql .= " LEFT JOIN sections AS s ON ms.section_id = s.id";
$sql .= " ORDER BY s.organisation ASC, s.name ASC, m.lastName ASC, m.firstName ASC";
$sql .= " LIMIT {$per_page} ";
$sql .= " OFFSET {$pagination->offset()}";
$members = Member::find_by_sql($sql);
```

Using the above query the following code outputs nothing for the s.name field, but all the fields from the members table are correctly listed. I know that the MySQL query is accessing the data, as the ORDER BY statement is correctly sorting the output.

```
  <?php foreach($members as $member): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $member->name;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $member->full_name();?></td>
    <td><?php echo $member->getAge($member->dob);?></td>
    <td><a href="member_edit.php?id=<?php echo $member->id;?>">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a href="member_delete_confirm.php?id=<?php echo $member->id;?>">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

If I output $members with print_r($members) it only contains the data from the members table, how do I access the data retrieved from the other tables?

Thanks

Comment: Be extremely careful when writing things like this. It looks like `$per_page` and `$pagination->offset()` are potential SQL injection points as they're not escaped properly.

Comment: What you doing there is NOT object oriented programming. It is just procedural code wrapped in a class.

Comment: @tadman The $per_page is being evaluated using (int) as part of the __contruct method in the Pagination Class. I have tried to push as much of the filtering and escaping down into the Classes as possible, to avoid the risk of overlooking the need to filter/escape on an individual basis. Having said that, as I am still trying to make the transition from 100% procedural I may well have overlooked or misunderstood something.

Comment: @tereško I must admit to still being less than 100% clear when it comes to defining OOP vs Class based programming particularly with a langauge such as PHP, so you may well be correct. I can only apologise if I have therefore mis-used the term "OOP" when "Class-based" would have been more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

You need to select them too here:

```
$sql = "SELECT s.name, m.id, m.firstName, m.lastName, m.dob";  
$sql .= " FROM members AS m";
$sql .= " LEFT JOIN mbr_sections AS ms ON m.id = ms.member_id";
$sql .= " LEFT JOIN sections AS s ON ms.section_id = s.id";
$sql .= " ORDER BY s.organisation ASC, s.name ASC, m.lastName ASC, m.firstName ASC";
$sql .= " LIMIT {$per_page} ";
$sql .= " OFFSET {$pagination->offset()}";
$members = Member::find_by_sql($sql);
```

You only selected name, id, firstName, lastName and dob.

Here is an example:

```
$sql = "SELECT s.name, m.id, m.firstName, m.lastName, m.dob, mbr_sections.field_you_want, sections.*";
```

Comment: Sorry - may not have been 100% clear, the s.name field is being selected from one of the joined tables (the other table,aliased as ms, is not actually needed for output, it only serves as a x-ref table.) So while I have selected s.name (from the joined table) in the query, I am unable to work out how to access it via the object.

Comment: You mean $member->name is empty? Are you sure it contains anything?

Comment: The print_r output is shown: Most fields are empty in this example, as I have not selected them, but the [name] value (at the end) was selected and has a value in he database, but appears empty in the results:      Array ( [0] => Member Object ( [id] => 1812 [lastName] => Williams [firstName] => Freya [gender] => ... [dob] => 0000-00-00 [noPhoto] => [nhsNumber] => [doctorName] => [doctorPhone] => [osm_id] => [osm_section_id] => [started] => [parents] => [notes] => [religion] => [ethnicity] => [joined] => [name] => )

Comment: Running the query directly against SQL produces the following output (the NULL values in the first records represents outstanding DB setup work), its the last record that I am using to test the output 
name id firstName lastName dob
Guides 1812 Freya Williams 0000-00-00
NULL 1726 Harrison Winship 0000-00-00
NULL 1756 Alexander Wolfe 0000-00-00
NULL 1830 Isobel Wolfe 0000-00-00
NULL 1774 Benjamin Woods 0000-00-00
NULL 1775 Isaac Yuill 0000-00-00
NULL 1813 Millie Yuill 0000-00-00
Scouts 1757 Neil Beckett 0000-00-00